# IOS - trigger navigation within script

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've followed this tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) to create a slide out view - all works fine - But I would like to add an alert button which when clicked navigates to the secondary view -

The tutorial advises that this action can be applied to the navigation bar button via the following-

```
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
```

How do I apply this to a standard button?  I have setup the button as _importantMsg - my code is below..  Basically I don't know how to convert the above to work within the below function..

Cheers

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_importantMsg addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImpMsg)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)buttonImpMsg
{
    NSLog(@"Alert Pressed");
    [self.revealViewController revealToggle:]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method definition is either

```
-(void)revealToggle;
```

or something like

```
-(void)revealToggle:(id)sender;
```

In the latter case you call it with

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggle:nil];
```

Look at the definition of your method to find out which it is. `revealToggle:` is certainly not valid syntax.

Of course, you could send the action to the other controller directly.

```
[[_importantMsg addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```